# How to reduce this if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

```
if(year%400==0 || (year%100!=0 && year%4==0))
```

statement is in the form of `a or (b' and c)`

Does this reduce to `a or (b or c')` ?

```
if(year%400==0 || (year%100==0 || year%4!=0))
```

Is there a mistake in this reduction? (I thought it was correct but these two does not give the same results.)

Comment: De Morgan's laws, it's a math question, not a C question. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve though?

Comment: A truth table will allow you to easily check whether the statements are equivalent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

Comment: Those aren't equivalent, if that's what you're really asking. Unrelated, per its definition, there is no 'reduction' here regardless.

Comment: For a start, you could simply test using years 1990-2010 and 2090-2110. Do both expression provide same result? This should quickly show they are not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this reduce to `a or ( b or c' )`?

No. You can see this by building a truth table.

---

We *can* change the `and` to an `or`.

```
  b' and c
= ( b' and c )''
= ( b or c' )'
```

so

```
a or ( b' and c )
```

becomes

```
a or ( b or c' )'
```

Not useful, except to show it's not equivalent to `a or ( b or c' )`.

---

We can change the `and` to an `or` using the same approach.

```
a or ( b' and c )
```

becomes

```
( a' and ( b or c' ) )'
```

Again, not useful.

---

It can be simplified to `year % 4 == 0`, as long as you only deal with the years 1901 to 2099.

Comment: if(year%400==0 || !(year%100==0 || year%4!=0))     worked as you said. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example of `year = 100`. Your first statement will return false, while the second will return true.

The second `or` statement enclosed in parentheses does not need to be, and so can be considered as a simple check of the three conditions individually.